# Confirm that a user has read and write access to current directory

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I am writing a script which will need to makes files and directories, but before it goes ahead and does that I want to run a check to see if the user running the script has read and write access. If so the script should continue, else it should tell the user they will need to try and run the script in a different directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via `test` command:

```
# doesn't  echo OK, because no read-write permissions
$ [ -r /proc/28127/task/28189/fd ] && [ -w /proc/28127/task/28189/fd  ] && echo "OK" 
# echoes OK, because my user has read-write permissions to the directory
$ [ -r $HOME ] && [ -w $HOME  ] && echo "OK"                                                          
OK
```

This can be put into a function and store that into `~/.bashrc` or used in a script:

```
check_dir() {
    [ -r "$1" ] && [ -w "$1" ] && echo "OK" 
}
```

And used as so:

```
$ check_dir $HOME
OK
```

Via `find` command:

```
# Doesn't return directory name because I don't have read/write permissions
$ find /proc/28127/task/28189/fd -maxdepth 0 -readable -writable                                      

# Returns  directory name, because I can write/read there
$ find $HOME  -maxdepth 0 -readable -writable                                                         
/home/xieerq
```